# Laravel Livewire Timing Out

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Hey all you clever people, I need some help with some livewire, Im making a request to a external API in my component and im wanting to show that on the blade however it just keeps timing out so was wondering if anyone could help me my scripts are below and an exmaple of the ddd that I have before it renders the view and times out...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Livewire\Component;

class Users extends Component
{
    public $users;

    public function render()
    {
        $response = Http::get('http://url/api/all');
        $response = $response->json();
        $users = $response['data'];
        dd($users);

        return view('livewire.users', compact(['users']));
    }
}
```

This is an example of the DD $users

```
array:13 [▼
  "current_page" => 1
  "data" => array:7 [▶]
  "first_page_url" => "http://url/api/all?page=1"
  "from" => 1
  "last_page" => 1
  "last_page_url" => "http://url/api/all?page=1"
  "links" => array:3 [▶]
  "next_page_url" => null
  "path" => "http://url/api/all"
  "per_page" => 15
  "prev_page_url" => null
  "to" => 7
  "total" => 7
]
```

However if I take the DD out and try and render the view it just times out this is my view blade.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@livewire('users')

    {{dd($users)}}

@endsection
```

Ive tried with $this->users and also with compact that you see in the exmaples, If anyone of you know what I could be doing wrong could you guide me into the right directions..

Im an API guy im not so good with frontend stuff ahaha

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

According to Caleb, creator of livewire, "We recently implemented a pretty big internal security feature that may have caused issues."

See a recent comment from him on GitHub issue [Session expire after 30s-1min when using livewire components directly with Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2475#issuecomment-775976568)

He suggests, to either downgrade to version 2.3.8 or it's recent update 2.3.18.